# XML fail to load with error

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I'd like to parse an `xml` file with `PHP`. I used this code:

```
$images = parsage("Rambod_catalog.xml", "Thumbnail");
$prices = parsage("Rambod_catalog.xml", "Retail_Price");
echo sizeof($images);

function getindex($element, $liste) {
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($liste);$i) {
        if($liste[$i] == $element)return $i;
    }
    return 0;
}

function parsage($document, $noeud) {
    $document_xml = new DomDocument;
    $document_xml->load($document);
    $elements = $document_xml->getElementsByTagName($noeud);
    return $elements;
}
```

but i got this exception:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: I/O warning :
failed to load external entity "/Rambod_catalog.xml"
```

So, what is the problem? How can i fix my code?

Comment: File does not exists. It's absolute path starting in `/`. You can fix it by providing full path (like `/home/lamolumi/www/file.xml`)

Comment: see my edit , it parses this time but it returns 1 value despites it is 900 images tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"/Rambod_catalog.xml"
```

The path you have given is invalid. What you have wrote there is, unfortunately, referring to filesystem root. either the file is stored in the current directory and you delete the leading slash or specify a full path. (include_path is at times unreliable).

you should refer to files like CONSTANT_TO_DOCUMENT_ROOT.PATH_SEPARATOR.$fileName in order to be flexible.

also see [getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) and [$_SERVER global variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and in need, print_r or var_dump the [reserved globlas](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php) to find what you might use for the CONSTANT_TO_DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Comment: also ... this doesn't make sense ... `for($i=0;$i<sizeof($liste);$i){` ... perhaps $i++ for the next value ?